# Words attaining different meanings

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, antonyms

If jail and prison are (at least nearly) synonymous, why does jailer refer to the captor, and prisoner refer to the captive? Are there similar examples?

Comment: Like most "why" questions about language, the answer is "Because that's the way it is". You  may be able to find a historical account of the stages the words went through, but there's never really an answer to "why".

Comment: ... Why are 'escapee' and the rarer 'escaper' synonymous? Contrast employee/employer; biographee/biographer; kidnappee/kidnapper; awardee/awarder; pledgee/pledger; payee/payer ....

Comment: Prison and jail are really quite different—in the United States at least. Why would different words originating at different times and places for different purposes have the same structures?

Comment: A [keeper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keeper) is either someone who keeps or someone/something that you should keep; lots of other -er words like eater (someone who eats/apple for eating), maker, rocker, dresser, marker, chaser, walker, pointer, cooker, drawer, charger, toner, dumper, looker, etc, have multiple meanings, as agent, tool/instrument, and/or object. This is an interesting game, but off-topic. And a stander and standee both stand.

Comment: If a question is asked in this forest, and no one hears it as a direct copy (at least nearly), does it make a sound question?

Comment: Fox and vixen are the same word from different dialects. One got the vowel shift and the other got frozen.